# Python idiom for applying a function only when value is not None

Tags: python, nonetype

A function is receiving a number of values that are all strings but need to be parsed in various ways, e.g.

```
vote_count = int(input_1)
score = float(input_2)
person = Person(input_3)
```

This is all fine except the inputs can also be `None` and in this case, instead of parsing the values I would like to end up with `None` assigned to the left hand side. This can be done with

```
vote_count = int(input_1) if input_1 is not None else None
...
```

but this seems much less readable especially with many repeated lines like this one. I'm considering defining a function that simplifies this, something like

```
def whendefined(func, value):
    return func(value) if value is not None else None
```

which could be used like

```
vote_count = whendefined(int, input_1)
...
```

My question is, is there a common idiom for this? Possibly using built-in Python functions? Even if not, is there a commonly used name for a function like this?

Comment: What you already have (`whendefined`) looks fine to me.

Comment: Just curious - why `vote_count` being None is better that just assigning `0` to it? Feels like there would be less amount of ifs in subsequent code.

Comment: Btw, as your inputs are always strings you can shorten the expression to `vote_count = int(input_1) if input_1 else None`. (this will yield also `None` if `input_` = "")

Comment: @thefourtheye just wondering if there is any solution from the standard library that I missed. Also I'm wondering if there is a better name than `whendefined`.

Comment: @Nsh sometimes it is necessary to explicitly model a missing value.

Comment: @jonls:  I would have named the function something like `keep_none_arg`.  Your original conditional expression could be shorter if you reverse logic `None if input_1 is None else int(input_1)`, but of course that puts the expected case to the right side of the expression.  I question the need to propagate `None` values.  Better would be to provide a sensible default otherwise you are going to be having to do this logic yet again when you use variables like `vote_count`.  Perhaps your current problem exists because you did not trap the problematic value upstream.

Comment: @jonls sure, but is it a case? What if `input_1` is not parseable to int? Is it "missing" value, same as `None`? Are you covering this execution path in your approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In other languages there's [Option typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type), which is a bit different (solves the problem with a type system), but has the same motivation (what do do about nulls).

In Python there's more of a focus on runtime detection of this kind of thing, so you can wrap the function with an None-detecting guard (rather the data which is what Option typing does).

You could write a decorator that only executes a function if the argument is not None:

```
def option(function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if len(args) > 0 and args[0] is not None:
          return function(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

You should probably adapt that third line to be more suitable to the kind of data you're working with.

In use:

```
@option
def optionprint(inp):
    return inp + "!!"

>>> optionprint(None)
# Nothing

>>> optionprint("hello")
'hello!!'
```

and with a return value

```
@option
def optioninc(input):
    return input + 1

>>> optioninc(None)
>>> # Nothing

>>> optioninc(100)
101
```

or wrap a type-constructing function

```
>>> int_or_none = option(int)
>>> int_or_none(None)
# Nothing
>>> int_or_none(12)
12
```

Comment: `option(int)(input_1)` is not an improvement over `whendefined(int, input_1)`.  (Note that I didn't use `option` as a decorator because OP is calling builtin functions on 2 of his 3 examples.)

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I agree, I like the `option` decorator but I don't think it leads to more readable code in my case.

Comment: It's a good point, but I'm talking about creating a wrapper rather than an extra function in a chain at execution. In doing so it declares intention in a more 'static' way. I think it would be fair to define `int_or_none = option(int)` then `int_or_none(12)`. I think it ultimately comes down to style.

Comment: @jonls entirely up to you and how explicit you want to be. Using the option for decorator for defining your own functions would result in functions known always to have this decorator as part of their semantics. Using it for built-in types would suggest to me (as per my previous comment) that you declare a new type constructor function, e.g. `int_or_none`. This may or may not be horribly un-Pythonic, but makes sense from other languages' directions.

Comment: @Joe Thanks, that makes sense. I think the code in your last edit is much more relevant to my use case than the other two examples.

Answer (score 4):

If you can safely treat falsy values (such as 0 and the empty string) as None, you can use boolean and:

```
vote_count = input_1 and int(input_1)
```

Since it looks like you're taking strings for input, this might work; you can't turn an empty string to an int or float (or person) anyway. It's not overly readable for some, though the idiom is commonly used in Lua.

Comment: This could be a maintainability time-bomb! Today it's used with strings and works fine. In a year's time it's used with numbers and mysteriously 0s are treated as `None`s.

Comment: @Joe I don't believe that would be a problem with a small script.

Answer (score 0):

The [`opytional` library](https://github.com/mmore500/opytional) expresses this pattern nicely using an interface inspired by C++'s `std::optional`.

```py
>>> import opytional as opyt
>>> input_1 = "3"
>>> opyt.apply_if(input_1, int)
"1"
>>> input_2 = None
>>> opyt.apply_if(input_2, int)
None
```

The library also provides `or_else` and `or_value` for safe, expressive handling of values that may be None. Installation is available via pip, `python3 -m pip install opytional`.

*Disclaimer*: am library author